# QGIS loading and displaying specific data

Tags: qgis

I have following file (small extract out of long file)

| X | Y | 0m | 10m | 20m | 30m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45083332 | 5376997 | 1,576 | 0,948 | 0,779 | 0,667 |
| 45083332 | 5376997 | 1,676 | 0,968 | 0,789 | 0,687 |
| 45083332 | 5376997 | 1,776 | 0,988 | 0,799 | 0,697 |
| 45083332 | 5376997 | 1,676 | 0,968 | 0,789 | 0,687 |
| 45083332 | 5376997 | 1,576 | 0,948 | 0,779 | 0,667 |

X and Y are the coordinates, the values in the other columns are values for 0m, 10m 20m and 30m distance from the coordinates.

I would like to plot a line between the coordinates and colorcode in the respective distance on both sides of the line the value.

the line could look like this
[image]

But of course going from coordinate to coordinate and changing according to value.

Importing the file is not the problem. But usually I just get dots ath the coordinates and not a connected line plus I need the color coding according to distance left and right from line.

How could I do this?

Comment: Hi, i think these are two questions. Maybe it helps breaking it up? For the line you can look into the *points to path* tool in the toolbox. For the color-coding into the "layer-styling options and craft something custom.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Ok I can connect the dots with the points to path, but than I loose the information connected to each point. So how do I make the line "colorful" with data?